# Double type output

Tags: java, double

I can't understand why first print is 0.9999999999999 and second is 2.0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       double value = 0.9999999999999999;

       System.out.println(value);

       value = 1.9999999999999999;

       System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: Remember that computers use binary and limited memory. That number can't be stored well in binary with its limited memory, so it gets truncated to something that it *can* store.

Comment: @4castle That number *can* be stored in binary. It cannot be stored with accuracy in a *floating-point* number, but there are other binary representations that can store it correctly.

Comment: For the first value you specify 16 significant digits, for the second you specify 17.

Comment: @Andreas Only an object like `BigDecimal`, but there aren't any primitive types in Java that can.

Comment: @4castle I know that, but you didn't say *primitive type*, you just said *binary*, so I was trying to point out that your wording was wrong, since `BigDecimal` stores values in *binary* too, and it can store values like that just fine.

Comment: @4castle thank you, now I understand.